# Ionic installation stuck on Packages like lodash and media-typer

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

When I am started installing ionic on my pc process is stopped on

fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule media-typer@0.3.0 checking installable status
or some time

fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule loadash@verion checking installable status

Answer (score 0):

Try writing command with 
sudo and then your cmd